# Expression performance of overload operator?

Tags: performance, operators

1. (i++) and (i = i + 1)
2. (i += n) and (i = i + n)

which is better (performance)?

Comment: You're looking for speed in all the wrong places ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**It doesn't matter**

The compiler will convert statements like that to (what it thinks, and often is) their most efficient form.

I'd recommend you write statements like this in the same way as the rest of your code base in order to keep consistency.

If you are just doing your own thing on a personal project you can either do what you prefer or what is common for your particular language.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter, the performance is the same. In 1978 when C was invented these would map to different PDP-11 instructions, resulting in faster performance of `++` and `+=`. These days, however, the operations are optimized into the same exact sequences of instructions.